# Grails use Promises to answer AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, multithreading, grails

I'm trying to leverage multithreading in Grails to handle AJAX calls. The webpage fires an AJAX call, the controller allocates a new thread doing that job, and when it finishes, the result is returned and rendered. Here's my attempt. It failed. Seemingly **the second AJAX call was not fired at all.**

In the javascript in gsp: Two AJAX calls. The 1st one triggers the 2nd when complete.

```
function asynchroCrawl(){
    var jsonData = $.ajax(
            {
                url : "${createLink(controller:'environment', action:'asynchroCrawl')}",
                dataType : "json",
                async : true
            }).done(function(jsonData) {
                console.log("Crawler completed");
                crawlFinished=true;
                asynchroWordCloud();
    });
}
function asynchroWordCloud() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax(
                    {
                        url : "${createLink(controller:'environment', action:'asynchroKeywords')}",
                        dataType : "json",
                        async : false
                    }).done(function(jsonData) {                    
                keywordFinished = true; 
            });
}
```

In the controller: The other acton function is omitted.

```
def asynchroCrawl={
    User u=session.getAttribute("user");
    FrameworkController.crawlStarted=true;
    println "Crawling task started.";
    def p=task{
        NetworkGenerator.formNetwork(u);
    }
    p.onError { Throwable err -> println "An error occured \n${err.message}" }
    p.onComplete { result ->
        println "User crawl complete.";
        FrameworkController.crawlComplete=true;
        render u as JSON;
        return;
    }
}
```

NetworkGenerator is just a normal class that runs some job and updates the User object with `User.withTransaction{u.merge();}`

My understanding is that a Promise is created and handles my job, and when it is complete, the data should be returned to the webpage answering to the AJAX call. So the `.done()` function should also be fired, leading the flow to another AJAX call. However, the `done()` is never triggered. I see no "Crawler completed" printed in my browser console.

In my IDE console I do see "User crawl complete.", indicating the promise has completed. But an exception follows, saying:

```
2015-12-10 21:05:47,540 [Actor Thread 7] ERROR gpars.LoggingPoolFactory  -  Async execution error: null
Message: null
Line | Method
->> 1547 | notifyAttributeAssigned in org.apache.catalina.connector.Request
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1538 | setAttribute            in     ''
|    541 | setAttribute . . . . .  in    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
|    288 | setAttribute            in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
|    431 | storeGrailsWebRequest . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
|     61 | doCall                  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.async.WebRequestPromsiseDecorator$_decorate_closure1
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     61 | doCall                  in org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onComplete_closure1
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     62 | run                     in groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1
```

Please could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: it's not how it works. request is already processed at this moment. and you have to make a response there (or use Servlet 3.0 async, but anyway I don't see how it can help you). just remove async code from server action, you don't need it there, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: also, things like `FrameworkController.crawlStarted=true` makes your controller non thread safe, you shouldn't store user state in shared variable (controller class have only one instance, shared between multiple requests)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov this is true only when `static scope = 'singleton'` is set. Per default each request creates a new controller instance. so it;s perfectly fine to put some variables inside

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Thanks. I wasn't aware of that :)

Comment: @injecteer hm, I thought it's configured by default, at least docs says that "_Newly created applications have the grails.controllers.defaultScope property set to a value of "singleton" in application.yml_"

Comment: @IgorArtamonov in my 2.3.11 app there's no such line in Config, but in 2.4.2 there is. Anyway, my statement remains valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each servlet request is already serving within a thread, so there's no need to spawn another thread. You can spawn a new thread in an action - either with `new Thread().start()` or with GPars - doesn't really matter.

What matters is, that you have to **wait** (with `thread.join()` or alike) till the thread completes, so that your action can deliver the results your JS code expects

Comment: Thank injecteer I didn't know it! That was why I attempted to implement multi-threading myself.